# Kotlin app view overlaping with system navigation bar

Tags: android, kotlin

Using a android phone (samsung), my app view is being overlapped by the system navigation bar.  I'd like the view to be end at above the system navigation bar

screenshot of issue

[image: 1]

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_main" />
        />


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

Tried a bunch of different xml options, with the expectation of the view ending before the system navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out had the code below in my activity.

```
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

removed that and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).